# Call a static method from a .NET atribute

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

In .NET can I call a static method from an attribute.  Something like this

```
<PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role:="<call static method>")>
```

The reason I want to do this is because I want the method to do some logic based on the environment I am in and allow the user access or not

Is this possible?

Comment: Your role handling should be done in the pipeline. Yes, what you're trying to do has already been done (but not in the approach you're taking). Typically you'd write something like `Authorize[Role = "Admin"]` and have the pipeline check that the user is authenticated, *and* that they have the role 'Admin'.

Comment: @David **why** need do that?

Comment: Different roles will be created in different environments so whilst the role may be 'Admin' in production it may not be 'Admin' in development or other enviorments

Answer (score 5):

Attribute parameters are hard-coded in the assembly at compile time.

That is completely impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using custom attributes, take a look to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56(v=vs.110).aspx